# Can't open Rails console after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04, libreadline.so.7 not found

Tags: updates, ruby, rails

Last night I updated Ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04 . I'm a Ruby on Rails developer and I haven't been able to launch Rails console since the update.

I'm getting an error related to libreadline.so.7 . I've tried a few things such as reinstalling Rails or creating a symlink but it didn't work. I also tried getting the package from the console but it says there's not candidate for download.

```
find /usr/lib -name "libffi.so*" 

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.7
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.7.1.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6.0.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6

rails c

Traceback (most recent call last):
    14: from ./bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
    13: from ./bin/rails:4:in `require'
    12: from /home/elianvm/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    11: from /home/elianvm/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
    10: from /home/elianvm/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/command.rb:70:in `find_by_namespace'
     9: from /home/elianvm/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:39:in `lookup'
     8: from /home/elianvm/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:39:in `each'
     7: from /home/elianvm/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:40:in `block in lookup'
     6: from /home/elianvm/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:40:in `each'
     5: from /home/elianvm/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in lookup'
     4: from /home/elianvm/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:44:in `require'
     3: from /home/elianvm/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
     2: from /home/elianvm/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.4/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:4:in `require'
     1: from /home/elianvm/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/irb/completion.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
/home/elianvm/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/irb/completion.rb:10:in `require': libreadline.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/elianvm/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-linux/readline.so (LoadError)
```

I don't really understand what is going on so I don't know what else to try. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like the libreadline.so link didn't get updated to the .8 version.  Try reinstall of the libreadline8 and or libreadline-dev packages.

Comment: @ubfan1 what would be the commands? sudo apt install libreadline didn't work.

Comment: The package name is libreadline8.  Notice the "8" at the end.  The dev package does not have the 8.

Comment: That didn't work. The package downloads and installs but the error persists. Does this mean I unistalled it somewhere during the Ubuntu upgrade process?

Comment: I suppose the rails executable could have been linked with the ..so.7 version.  In that case, update the rails package or  you can kluge a fix simply adding the .7 link yourself to the ...so.8.0 version.  i cd to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu , then sudo ln -s libreadline.so.8.0 libreadline.so.7

Answer (score 0):

Check your `Gemfile.lock`. It'll list what version of everything the rails app is looking for. It's probably got the `0.7` version in there. From the `Gemfile.lock`, you can look up which gem is using `libreadline` and look for a version where the newer version is implemented. In your `Gemfile`, specify the appropriate version and you should be good to go.